# Resources when opening a website

Tags: hyperlink, web, resources, uri

When we open a website, the browser will open other links to retrieve various resources, not just the site link itself. I'd like to know the links that browser connect when opening a site. Is there a tool to determine this thing?

Comment: [What are you asking in specific and why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that you are looking for the full details of all assets needed to load a webpage.

The easiest option is to use the "developer Tools" in the browser. This is the F12 key often times. There is a network tab that will show all assets loaded and a timeline in which they were loaded.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i am looking for. Thank you very much.